# Target Angular binding with SCSS / CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, angular, sass

I am migrating an application from AngularJS to Angular.  I have just moved a `loading-indicator` component to Angular, and that has an optional modal binding to say whether its a modal loader or not.

In reality this doesnt bind to anything right now, it simply matches a CSS rule.

HTML

```
<loading-indicator [modal]="true"></loading-indicator>
```

SCSS

```
loading-indicator {    
    &[modal="true"] {
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }
}
```

The SCSS above targets an attribute of `modal` not `[modal]`.

How do I target `[modal]`?  I saw some answers suggesting I can escape the brackets using `\\` e.g. `&\\[[modal\\]]` but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: What if add dynamic class to `loading-indicator` ? Like this `<loading-indicator [modal]="true" [class.my-class]="true(or false)"></loading-indicator>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Because `[modal]="true"` for Angular it's an input and this will be converted to another HTML attribute.

You can use `modal=true` in your component and you can select this with

```
[modal=true] {
    /*styles*/
}
```

But for encapsulation, you need to put this style on the root styles of the app.

It's a better solution to bind the input modal value to a `[ngClass]=""`:

Inside the component ts **loading-indicator**:

```
@Input() modal;
```

On the template use:

```
<div [ngClass]="modal ? 'modal-background' : ''"></div>
```

On the styles of component:

```
.modal-background{
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```